# Display Wordpress Archives one category at a time?

Tags: wordpress, categories, archive

I am almost done with my humble attempt at a custom CMS using Wordpress. The only difficulty I have is making a page display the archive for only one category (and it's children). Anyone has an idea?
Thanks a lot!
Regis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom archive page using the class [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). Specifically, something like:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query('category_name=code'); ?>  
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- display the category here --> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can look at the default theme's archive.php to get a feel for what else is needed to display a particular category in a layout you are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to show a list of titles and permalinks for the category "mycategory"; this can go inside the main Wordpress loop:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=-1'); ?><?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php endwhile; ?>
```

Change the "-1" to "1" to show only the one most recent post; to "10" to show the last 10 posts, etc.